# Plotting two boxplots using the same variable in one figure in base R

Tags: r

I'm trying to plot two boxplots in the same figure in base R, one boxplot for the values of PM2.5 of which RAIN is 0 and hour is 12, the other for values of PM2.5 when RAIN is greater than 0 and hour is 12. This is a small part of my data set, called 'dat':

```
     No year month day hour PM2.5 PM10 SO2 NO2   CO O3 TEMP   PRES  DEWP RAIN  wd WSPM      station
1  7345 2014     1   1    0    20   90  18  62   NA NA -1.5 1007.3 -12.5    0 SSE  0.6 Aotizhongxin
2  7346 2014     1   1    1    43  348  25  91 1100  1 -2.6 1006.9 -12.1    0 WSW  0.2 Aotizhongxin
3  7347 2014     1   1    2    79  423  41 103 1800  1 -3.0 1006.9 -11.3    0 WSW  0.6 Aotizhongxin
4  7348 2014     1   1    3    82  337  43 101 2100  1 -3.3 1006.4 -11.1    0  SW  0.6 Aotizhongxin
5  7349 2014     1   1    4   124  594  59 130 2400  1 -2.7 1006.1 -10.5    0 ENE  1.8 Aotizhongxin
6  7350 2014     1   1    5    89  307  47 102 2500  1 -3.1 1006.6 -10.4    0   N  1.0 Aotizhongxin
7  7351 2014     1   1    6    59  161  45  91 1900  1 -2.6 1007.2 -10.9    0   S  1.0 Aotizhongxin
8  7352 2014     1   1    7    31   93  24  69  900  4 -2.9 1007.9 -10.2    0  SE  1.1 Aotizhongxin
```

This is what I've tried so far but I just get one boxplot out from it:

```
not_rainy <- subset(dat, dat$hour == 12 & dat$RAIN == 0)
rainy <- subset(dat, dat$hour == 12 & dat$RAIN > 0)
vals <- c(rainy$PM2.5,not_rainy$PM2.5)
boxplot(vals)
```

What should I change with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to `c`oncatenate the two subsets:

```
not_rainy <- subset(dat, dat$hour == 12 & dat$RAIN == 0)
rainy <- subset(dat, dat$hour == 12 & dat$RAIN > 0)
# vals <- c(rainy$PM2.5,not_rainy$PM2.5)
boxplot(not_rainy, rainy)
```

Answer (score 1):

ggplot is usually the answer:

```
library(ggplot2)

dat$rainy <- dat$RAIN > 0
ggplot(dat[dat$hour == 12,], aes(rainy, PM2.5)) + geom_boxplot()
```

Answer (score 1):

**If you want to do it with the base plotting system:**

Maybe you could try a multi-panel plot by adjusting the mfrow parameter:

```
par(mfrow=c(2, 1))
```

Then you can call`boxplot()` with both datasets:

```
boxplot(rainy)
boxplot(not_rainy)
```

**You can also do it with ggplot2**:

-You can map a categorical logical variable/parameter to the
"x" argument of the `aes()` and use `+geom_boxplot()`, as suggested by @dash2.
-Another option: put your data in the long format by calling something
like:

```
data.frame(data=vals, rainy=c(rep(c(TRUE, FALSE), times=length(rainy)), rep(c(TRUE, FALSE), times=length(not_rainy))))
```

Then use use `+facet_wrap(~rainy)` in your call to ggplot

**Another option is to use the cowplot package:**

Create two ggplot objects and save them*:

```
plot1<-ggplot(rainy, aes(y=PM2.5))+geom_boxplot()
plot2<-ggplot(not_rainy, aes(y=PM2.5))+geom_boxplot()
```

Then use `cowplot::plot_grid()`:

```
cowplot::plot_grid(plot1, plot2)
```

*This can also be used with base plots